# Conditional date option for php function - wordpress (ACF) plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, date, conditional-statements, advanced-custom-fields

This is the first time I've posted something in Stack Overflow and my php programming knowledge does have holes in it. Nonetheless, if some one could help me resolve the below issue I'd be eternally grateful.

I've created a list of items that each have a 1) Title, 2) Link, 3) Date & 4) description, that are inputed via the ACF plugin on a wordpress site. I have included the code to display this list on the front end of the website below - please note there are a series of lists meaning there are nested lists (called sub repeater) inside the main one (called parent repeater).

However . . . I wish to create an additional list above the nested list, which features any entries (inputted into the sub repeater) which are newer that 30 days. So creating 2 nested (sub repeater) lists inside (parent repeater) list.

So . . . I need to create a conditional "if" statement that separates out the "item list details" newer than 30 days (for example) and places them in a (sub repeater) list, followed by an "else" where all "item list details" older than 30 days are displayed in a separate (sub repeater) list.

Please can someone explain how I can generate this condition within the code below - FYI this code currently works successfully and generates nested (sub repeater) lists inside (parent repeater) lists, but I need to split out the (sub repeater) lists into 2 separate lists - one featuring items newer than 30 days and the other featuring all other items (which would be older than 30 days).

```
<?php 
    // check for rows (parent repeater)
    if( have_rows('membership_lists_links') ): ?>
        <?php 
        // loop through rows (parent repeater)
        while( have_rows('membership_lists_links') ): the_row(); ?>
           <div>
                <h2 class="acf-admin"><?php the_sub_field('item_list_title'); ?></h2>
                <?php 
                // check for rows (sub repeater)
                if( have_rows('item_list_details') ): ?>
                    <ul class="admin">
                    <?php
                    // loop through rows (sub repeater)
                    while( have_rows('item_list_details') ): the_row() 
                        // display each item as a list
                        ?>
                           <li><div class='itemTitle'>
                                    <?php $link = get_sub_field('link_url'); if( $link ): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" title="<?php echo $link['title']; ?>">
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php the_sub_field('link_name'); ?>
                                    <?php $link = get_sub_field('link_url'); if( $link ): ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="memberListDate">
                                    <?php the_sub_field('date'); ?>
                                </div>
                                <br/>
                                <div class="itemDescription">
                                    <?php the_sub_field('link_description'); ?>
                                </div>
                            </li>   
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; //if( get_sub_field('section_details') ): ?>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; // while( has_sub_field('business_sections') ): ?>
```

I presume that the section of the code that starts off . . .

```
<?php // check for rows (sub repeater)
if( have_rows('item_list_details') ): ?>
```

is where the date age condition needs to happen. Then I can create a list of items newer than 30 days and followed by an "else" which contains a list of all items older than 30 days.

I hope I've explained myself well enough and would massively appreciate any help with achieving this. As i said earlier, my php knowledge does have holes in it but hope that by engaging with the Stack Overflow community, I can learn more and hopefully help others further down the line.

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Repeater values are stored in arrays, so I'm going to use a foreach loop on the repeaters instead of using the ACF `have_rows()` and `the_row()` functions - I think it will be a little easier to understand this way.

Also, this answer will depend on how you set up the Date field. If you're using the built in Date Picker field, select `Ymd` as the return format in the field's settings. If you pull the current date in the same format you can compare those values:

```
<?php 
$membershipListLinks = get_field('membership_lists_links');

$lastMonth = date('Ymd', strtotime('-30 days'));

// check for rows (parent repeater)    
if( $membershipListLinks ): ?>
    <?php 
    // loop through rows (parent repeater)
    foreach( $membershipListLinks as $membershipListLink ): 
        $title = $membershipListLink['item_list_title'];
        $details = $membershipListLink['item_list_details'];
        ?>
        <div>
            <h2 class="acf-admin"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
            <?php 
            // check for rows (sub repeater)
            if( $details ): 
                // create some arrays
                $older = array();
                $newer = array();
                foreach( $details as $detail ): 
                    $date = $detail['date']; // make sure to return in Ymd format
                    // add the items to one of the empty arrays
                    if( $date < $lastMonth ) {
                        $older[] = $detail;
                    } else {
                        $newer[] = $detail;
                    }
                    $arrays = array($older, $newer);
                    foreach( $arrays as $array ):
                        if( !empty($array) ):
                        ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                            foreach( $array as $detail ):
                                $link = $detail['link_url'];
                                $name = $detail['link_name'];
                                $date = $detail['date'];
                                $description = $detail['link_description'];
                                // display each item as a list
                                ?>
                                <li>
                                    <div class="itemTitle">
                                        <?php if( $link ): ?>
                                        <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" title="<?php echo $link['title']; ?>">
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php echo $name; ?>
                                        <?php if( $link ): ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="memberListDate">
                                        <?php echo $date; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <br/>
                                    <div class="itemDescription">
                                        <?php echo $description; ?>
                                    </div>
                                </li>   
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT:

```
<?php 
$membershipListLinks = get_field('membership_lists_links');

$lastMonth = date('Ymd', strtotime('-30 days'));

// check for rows (parent repeater)    
if( $membershipListLinks ): ?>
    <?php 
    // loop through rows (parent repeater)
    foreach( $membershipListLinks as $membershipListLink ): 
        $title = $membershipListLink['item_list_title'];
        $details = $membershipListLink['item_list_details'];
        ?>
        <div>
            <h2 class="acf-admin"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
            <?php 
            // check for rows (sub repeater)
            if( $details ): 
                // create some arrays
                $older = array();
                $newer = array();
                foreach( $details as $detail ) { 
                    $date = $detail['date']; // make sure to return in Ymd format
                    // add the items to one of the empty arrays
                    if( $date < $lastMonth ) {
                        $older[] = $detail;
                    } else {
                        $newer[] = $detail;
                    }
                }    
                $arrays = array('older' => $older, 'newer' => $newer);
                foreach( $arrays as $key => $value ):
                    if( !empty($value) ):
                    ?>
                    <ul class="<?php echo ($key == 'older') ? 'older' : 'newer'; // change as needed ?>">
                        <?php
                        foreach( $value as $detail ):
                            $link = $detail['link_url'];
                            $name = $detail['link_name'];
                            $date = $detail['date'];
                            $description = $detail['link_description'];
                            // display each item as a list
                            ?>
                            <li>
                                <div class="itemTitle">
                                    <?php if( $link ): ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>" title="<?php echo $link['title']; ?>">
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php echo $name; ?>
                                    <?php if( $link ): ?>
                                    </a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="memberListDate">
                                    <?php echo $date; ?>
                                </div>
                                <br/>
                                <div class="itemDescription">
                                    <?php echo $description; ?>
                                </div>
                            </li>   
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hi Johnny. Many thx for your code. A few questions if that's OK?

Comment: @PhilLegg shoot

Comment: Hi Johnny. Many thanks for the code. A few questions if that's OK? 1) In terms of date format - I'm returning j M Y - is that a problem? - 2) I was thinking of making the number if days before it swaps to the other list adjustable - therefore If I was to make the number of days an ACF field called "latest_additions" can I just go:  `$lastMonth = date('Ymd', strtotime( get_sub_field('latest_additions') ) );` - and 3) If I wanted to style the new list differently. How would I create a different class for the new list using your coding method? Thanks Phil

Comment: 1) Use Ymd as the return value in order for you to make the comparison. When it comes time to output the date you can change it to whatever you want (Advanced example here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/)
2) Yes, that should work if the value was '-30 days'
3) The easy way would be to just run a foreach loop on each array instead of creating the `$arrays` array

Comment: Hi Johnny trying to get this to work. RE issue 3) about styling the "latest" list: can I not keep the code edit you've supplied but include an if statement in the <ul to echo a class name like this: `$arrays = array($older, $newer);
                    foreach( $arrays as $array ):
                        if( !empty($array) ):
                        ?>
                        <ul <?php if ( $date < $lastMonth ) { echo "class='latest_Addition'";} ?>>`

Comment: Not exactly - you have not defined the `$date` variable at that point. I actually just noticed an error in my answer - I'll adjust.

Comment: Big thanks for this Johnny. Worked well. Tried to mark your comments up but as I'm new it doesn't register apparently. On a slightly different note. . . If I wanted to have both New and Old list items in the same list. How could I code it so the list items under 30 days would have a different css class (so i can style them differently?). Any help would be most appreciated. Thx Phil